# How can I isolate two networks when one device is connected to both?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, debian

I want to run a private network that will allow devices to connect to it using wired connection, but some devices will be connected to a different WiFi connection that has access to the Internet.

Is there any way to prevent other devices in WLAN (phones, laptops) to access devices in LAN?

[image]

In this diagram, I need PC1 and PC4 to be able to communicate **only** to PC2, but without access to PC3 or another devices in the private subnet.

Assume all devices are running debian, just for simplify things.

Answer (score 2):

Well... Your best bet would be to purchase a networking switch that supports 802.1q (VLANs).  With VLANs, you will be able to virtually slice your network so that only certain machine communicate with other machines on the same VLAN.  You'll also be able to create routes for certain machines to access the internet and others to be blocked.  The cheaper way of not allowing machines to hit the internet is to get rid of their gateway or DNS address.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Ditto to what pythonian said.